# How can I calculate how many times a given subset of (finite) X will appear in the set of subsets of X of a particular size?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, binomial-theorem

Let $X$ be a finite set. Suppose $R$ is some proper subset of X. Let $S$ be the set of subsets of $X$ of a given size; for example, $S$ could be the set of three-membered subsets of $X$. Is there any way to calculate how many members of $S$ have $R$ as a subset?

[edited this question due to some unclarities in the formulation]

Comment: R will either appear or not appear in S depending on its size. Perhaps reclarify your question?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I was assuming that when $|R| > |s|$ (where $s$ is a given member of $S$) then the number of times $R$ appears in $S$ would be zero. But I may be overlooking something.

Comment: ya thats right. say S is the set of subsets of X of size n. then if |R| = n, R will be in S. otherwise it will not.

Answer (score 1):

You rightly mentioned that if $|R|>|s|,s\in S$, then the answer is $0$. On the other hand, if $|s|\ge|R|$, you can count the number of subsets of $X$ of size $|s|$ with $R$ as a subset. For that, note that $|R|$ elements are already fixed; they are the elements of $R$. You can select the remaining $|s|-|R|$ elements from the remaining $|X|-|R|$ elements of $X$ in $\displaystyle\binom{|X|-|R|}{|s|-|R|}$ ways, which is the answer.

Comment: This is great, thank you!